Opening local XYZ Tiles source on QGIS
I am trying to add an XYZ Tiles source of a map that I downloaded in PNG format to QGIS. It has been cached with Global Mapper. It works very well with Global Mapper and SASPlanet, but it appears like this on QGIS:

Here is the URL I used, what am I doing wrong?


By the tiling image, it looks like you have swapped x and y (or QGIS uses it differently from SASPlanet). Given that Antarctica is on the left, I think
file://I://TopPlsOpen//{z}//{x]//{y}.png

could work.

Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I've already tried reversing the x, y and z orders, and it gives the same thing :/ it's not divided into squares but into large horizontal tiles this time https://i.imgur.com/4Qu0hmm.png

It is getting better. Now it looks like a difference in the location of the first tile, top-left vs bottom-left. See https://documentation.maptiler.com/hc/en-us/articles/4405435316369-Tiling-scheme-in-Folder-output. Unfortunately the QGIS XYZ driver does not seem to have a control for that.

@Thomas Did you try {-y} to flip the vertical direction too?
